# Is there an add in for Visual Basic 6 that helps manage if/else and loop statements?

Tags: vb6, add-in

Visual Studio has the capability of code collapsing and at the very least has code help that enables you to keep your if/else statements and loops in order by indicating where they begin and end.  Is there anything like this for Visual Basic 6?

Thanks!

Comment: I've not seen anything explicitly for this, but proper nesting nad indentation should negate its need.

Comment: [MZ Tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/features.aspx#CodeFaster) lets you save frequently used code snippets. You could define `If-End If` pairs with matching comments that show which `End If` statements go with which `If` statement. Although IMO you should be marking these up like this anyway.

Answer (score 5):

If you have $249 laying around, check out [CodeSMART](http://www.axtools.com/products-codesmart-vb6.php#T4):

> 2.1. Branch Lines
>
> Branch Lines are drawn to emphasize control statement branches, that
>   is lines drawn between the opening and closing parts of each control
>   statement; very useful in visualizing code nesting.

[image: Branch Lines preview]